# How to get a product's Custom Fields in a different template file?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

so I have some Advanced Custom Fields on my product page. They are displayed in the shop loop, like so:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'tagline', 5);
function tagline() {
    global $product;
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
   
    if (isset(get_fields()['product_tagline'])) {
        $tagline = get_fields()['product_tagline'];
    }

        echo '<p class="tagline">' . $tagline . '</p>';
 
}
```

I'm also using ACF to select products in a post, so if we mention products in a blog post, I can select them to display as a sidebar. I'm struggling with getting the `$tagline` from my product fields to use in my sidebar.

I've tried `$tagline = get_fields()['product_tagline'];` but the result is `null`. Any idea of where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You have to pass the product ID as the first parameter to "get_fields()" function, because the default value for this parameter is the current global post ID which is the single post being displayed not the product.

Comment: Yes, that worked! And it makes sense, thank you!